# Owin AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie) not working for live id? workaround

Tags: asp.net-mvc, owin

I created a default MVC application using VS 2013 and using Owin authentication with live id as my external login provider, but sadly it doesn't work the way it should when it comes to signing out user from live id. I checked many solutions like using

```
AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
```

instead of

```
AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
```

but nothing works at all. I stumbled across this part where I am redirecting user to live id specific URL in my LogOff action method.

*(I just have live id authentication as my external login provider and no other, but if you are going with this approach with multiple login providers then you need to check if it is live id provider before redirecting)*

```
// POST: /Account/LogOff
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult LogOff()
    {
        AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return Redirect("https://login.live.com/oauth20_logout.srf?client_id=[your_client_id]&scope=wl.basic&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://www.yourdomain.com/signin-microsoft&state=");
    }
```

But when you actually run this and hit the logoff link, it will redirect you back to your app to "http://www.yourdomain.com/signin-microsoft&lc=2057" URL which shows a blank page and doesn't redirect to your home page. Now to fix this part, I wrote below code inside Global.asax

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var url = Request.Url;
        if(url.AbsoluteUri.Contains("signin-microsoft") && Request.QueryString["lc"] != null)
        {
            Response.Redirect(url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority));
        }
    }
```

I don't know if this is the only way for now.. Can anyone share if there is any better way to do this?